# Call JavaScript function from code behind in loop with parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using ' `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey", jsMethodName, true);`' for calling JavaScript function from C# codebehind.
It works fine. But, the problem is that while I using loop

```cs
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  string jsMethodName = "javascripttestfunction('" + parameter[i] + "','" +
    param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "')"; // callig javascript function from codebehind
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey", jsMethodName, true);
}
```

It takes only the first set of parameters. It does not take a remaining set.

Comment: The code runs fine as is... could one of your params be void during the for loop?

Comment: possiblly one of the params could be passing a special char that breaks your jsMethodName string

Comment: No, The javascript function triggers only first time with first set of argument

Comment: Try to move the "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock" into it's own function and then pass the string to that function in your for loop. That way "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock" can complete it's job and get disposed before you call it again.

Comment: @AnyMoose i tried that way but it's not working. I think "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock"  only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script Manager need different key,so please try below code.

```js
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  string jsMethodName = "javascripttestfunction('" + param[i] + "','" +
    param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "','" + param[i] + "')"; // callig javascript function from codebehind
  ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey"+i, jsMethodName, true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir :)